# Text not visible, when adding image

Tags: bug, support, status-norepro, design

Below is the screenshot, when I try to add the image, the text appear in the prompt box are not visible and hard to read and I'm using updated 24.0 Mozilla Firefox browser.

[image]

Comment: StackExchange admins...we keep getting these posts in meta. We really, REALLY need someone to do a redesign on our meta site. I think the whole "negative" approach, while intriguing, has not really worked out. I think we should stick with a copy of the main site, however instead of a white primary background, maybe a gray of some sort. Anyway, something really needs to be done about the usability and readability of our meta site! Thanks!

Comment: Noted. (Again.) I have been poking on this and will continue to do so (maybe with a stick this time).

Comment: We don't use mere sticks for poking here at Stack Exchange. We [soft, yet subtly fully automatic](http://www.geekosystem.com/nerf-stampede-automatic/) sticks.

Comment: Even just a temporary change to make the text a dark colour would be good as an interim solution.